# Query for tables with @ManyToMany relation(Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I rewrite my SpringMVC app with using Hibernate.I try to make query for selecting lectures for group of students by id of group.with using SQL query(before I started rewrite it with using Hibernate)this query was:

```
"SELECT * FROM lectures WHERE id IN (SELECT lecture_id FROM lectures_groups WHERE group_id =?) ORDER BY date_of_lecture"
```

I have Lecture and Group etities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lectures")
public class Lecture {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "lectures_groups", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lecture_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"))
    private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")
    private Teacher teacher;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id")
    private Subject subject;
    @Column(name = "date_of_lecture")
    private LocalDateTime date;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "audience")
    private Audience audience;

    public Lecture() {

    }
//getters setters
}
```

and:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "group_name")
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cathedra_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Cathedra cathedra;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "lectures_groups", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lecture_id"))
    private List<Lecture> lectures = new ArrayList<>();

    public Group() {

    }
//getters setters
}
```

I tried somthing like:

```
List<Lecture> lectures = session.createQuery("select l from lectures l join l.groups g where g.id=:groupId")
                .setParameter("groupId", group.getId())
                .list();
```

but I get Exception: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: lectures is not mapped
So how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `hql` query you need to provide the name of the `entity` in the query instead of the table name. So in your case, you should replace `lectures` with `Lecture` in the query.

```java
List<Lecture> lectures = session.createQuery("select l from Lecture l join l.groups g where g.id=:groupId")
                .setParameter("groupId", group.getId())
                .list();
```

Comment: oh god..Thanks!I spend several hours trying to resolve this, but not think about this!